# Google Chrome Theme with popup after installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, themes, google-chrome-theme

I'm trying to make a theme for google chrome, but I want to have a popup window appearing when it is installed. I'm not sure if it is even possible, because a theme isn't the same thing as an extension.

So I figured that with this manifest file I'd be able to do this with an extension:

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "script.js" ]
   },
   "description": "Een test",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test Extension",
   "version": "0.0.2"
}
```

In script.js I got this code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
  window.open('http://www.example.com','','width=800,height=500');
});
```

This all works good. Now the hard part is using this for a theme. The thing is just that when I add a theme object into the manifest file things don't seem to work properly: the script won't be executed anymore. So at this point my manifest file looks like this:

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "script.js" ]
   },
   "description": "Een test",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test Extension",
   "theme": {
      "colors": {
         "bookmark_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "frame": [ 12, 20, 30 ],
         "ntp_background": [ 11, 21, 35 ],
         "ntp_header": [ 40, 40, 40 ],
         "ntp_link": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_section": [ 255, 255, 255, 0.5 ],
         "ntp_section_link": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_section_text": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text": [ 10, 10, 10 ],
         "tab_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "toolbar": [ 6, 13, 21 ]
      },
      "images": {
         "theme_frame": "img/frame.jpg",
         "theme_frame_overlay": "img/frame_overlay.png",
         "theme_ntp_attribution": "img/ntp_attribution.png",
         "theme_ntp_background": "img/ntp_background.jpg",
         "theme_tab_background": "img/tab_background.jpg",
         "theme_tab_background_incognito": "img/tab_background.jpg",
         "theme_toolbar": "img/toolbar.jpg"
      },
      "properties": {
         "ntp_background_alignment": "bottom right",
         "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
      },
      "tints": {
         "buttons": [ 1, 1, 1 ]
      }
   },
   "version": "0.0.2"
}
```

I guess it doesn't work anymore because the file will now be classified as a theme. Still, I thought I could post this matter here. I hope you guys got suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (http://www.themebeta.com/chrome-theme-creator-online.html) to create your theme, it'l give a pop-up too.